# How to improve QQuickView refresh

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a application different mix UI : 
QWidget::createWindowContainer() for QML with QQuickView
And QWidget

When I try to create transition ( animation ) of my QWidget which content my QQuickView, the transition is not very smooth ...

Here my code summarized :

```
QQuickView *myQuickView = new QQuickView("myqml")
QState *mMenuStateHidden = new QState();
QState *mMenuStateVisible = new QState();

QStateMachine *mMachine = new QStateMachine();
mMachine->addState(mMenuStateHidden);
mMachine->addState(mMenuStateVisible);
mMahine->setInitialState(mMenuStateHidden);

mGSlideMenu = QWidget::createWindowContainer(myQuickView);

mMenuStateHidden->assignProperty(mGSlideMenu, "geometry", QRectF(QPointF(-mGSlideMenu->width(), height()),mGSlideMenu->size()));
mMenuStateVisible->assignProperty(mGSlideMenu, "geometry", QRectF(QPointF(0, height()),mGSlideMenu->size()));

QPropertyAnimation *lAnimOut = new QPropertyAnimation(mGSlideMenu, "geometry");


QSignalTransition *transition = mMenuStateHidden->addTransition(myQuickView->rootObject(), SIGNAL(menuClicked()), mMenuStateVisible);
        transition->addAnimation(lAnimIn);

QSignalTransition* transition2 = mMenuStateVisible->addTransition(myQuickView->rootObject(), SIGNAL(menuClicked()), mMenuStateHidden);
        transition2->addAnimation(lAnimOut);

mMahine->start();
```

How you can see, in the left of the gif, there are a "black" artifact; which is not there we the QML is not loaded.

[image: In the Left]

So my question is, how I can improve my QQuickView to have a application with a better smooth.

Thx guys,

Comment: Show your code to understand better, it would be great to show a gif of what you get to understand you better.

Comment: I edit my post.

Comment: How do you set the parameters of `lAnimOut`?

Comment: Re update, with full code now.

Comment: Note : When the qml file is not loading, the animation is smooth.

Comment: `menuClicked`??

Comment: emit from QML item

Comment: I update my post with the gif for more visual information

Comment: You must provide a mvce, this code should be minimal and reproducible and your code is not currently, if you do not want to show it here because it is extensive you can upload it to github or similar and share the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue in using a QQuickWidget instead QQuickView.
Everything is ok now.

Thx !